# RStudio is slow when loading a project / package in development

Tags: r, git, rstudio, dropbox

I have recently experienced a serious problem with Rstudio when developing a package. Whenever, I open an existing project with Rstudio where versions are controlled with Git, it takes so long for it to respond to any command. It is also impossible to type something in the console (e.g. 1+1) and obtain the result. Even quitting the Rstudio, should be done with task manager. There is no problem when I create a new project / package or when I open directly a R script.

This problem appears both when the project is saved on a dropbox or on a local repository.

To overcome this issue everytime I need to modify my code, I create a new project, and then I move toward the new repository all my current R scripts and the folder ".git".

I would appreciate if anybody could help me with this issue.

Comment: Seems like you're saving too much data in .RData file. Go to Tools - Project Options and turn off the saving/loading of data.

Comment: Same problem here, and no, I am not using .RData files. Have updated RStudio, any ideas?

Comment: Same issue, and .RData is turned off.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem to yours. Changing the attribute of my .git folder into `hidden` solved my problem.

> We recently discovered an issue where projects using git for version control could become laggy / unusable on Windows if the .git folder within the project had become a non-hidden directory.

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1918